# Nothing was returned from render in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the App `index.js` file I am handling redirects as `navigate` based on user authentication.

```
const IndexAuth = () => navigate(routes.DASHBOARD);

const IndexPageContent = withAuthorization(authCondition)(() => (
 <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (authUser ? <IndexAuth /> : null)}
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
));

export default withAuthentication(IndexPage);
```

The redirect works but I am getting an error at `IndexAuth` and causing the page at `routes.DASHBOARD` to not render.

```
IndexAuth(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

As I understand it, I need to return something for the component to `render`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IndexAuth is just a wrapper around navigate, then navigate needs to return something, which it doesn't. If navigate is your function, then add a return value to it. Otherwise, add it to IndexAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend on Joseph Sible's answer with a solution for others in the same boat.

I fixed the issue by returning `null` in `IndexAuth`

```
const IndexAuth = () => {
  navigate(routes.DASHBOARD);
  return null;
};
```